# Custom Query Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I need a custom Query in my Repository which extends CrudRepository

```
@Repository
public interface SongListRepository extends CrudRepository<SongList, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT sl FROM song_list sl WHERE sl.owner=:owner")
    Set<SongList> findAllSongListsForUser(
            @Param("owner") String owner);
}
```

When I try to start the following excpetion is thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'songListController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'songListService';

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'songListService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository';

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'songListRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Set htwb.ai.songsservice.repository.SongListRepository.findAllSongListsForUser(java.lang.String)!
```

How do i create custom Querys in a CrudRepository?

Comment: Try this as query: "select s from #{#entityName} s where s.owner = :owner"

Comment: seems to work thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create your own query. Simply use the auto generate query based on the method signature.

```
List<SongList> findAllByOwner(String owner);
```

This will create the query.